# Вывод массива

Tags: java

```
char a [] = testField3.getText().toCharArray();
textField1.setText("a []="+a);
```

В результате мне выдает не то, что я ввожу, а совсем другой текст. Например, я ввожу `12345`, а мне выдает `a[]=[C@e427ed`. Как cделать так, чтобы выводилось то же самое, что я вводил?

Answer (score 5):

```
textField1.setText(testField3.getText())
```

Если вы хотите именно этот массив засунуть обязательно, то

```
textField1.setText(new String(a));
```

Но тогда встаёт вопрос: а зачем тогда вы делали массив в первом случае.

**UPD**

И да, конечно же это потому, что вы не знаете основ, но пытаетесь ещё делать GUI. Надо сначала разобраться в основах и тогда не будет таких нелепых вопросов.

Comment: А может быть автор хотел получить вывод Arrays.toString(a); ?

Answer (score 4):

ваш код:

```
char a [] = testField3.getText().toCharArray();
textField1.setText("a []="+Arrays.toString ( a );
```

без лишнего конвертирования:

```
String b [] = testField3.getText();
textField1.setText("a []="+b);
```

тоже самое но без лишней переменной:

```
textField1.setText("a []="+testField3.getText());
```

*UPD*: главное правило програмиста - не копипасть! ошибку оставим там где есть. ниже напишем как правильно. во втором примере должно быть:

```
String b = testField3.getText();
textField1.setText("a []="+b);
```

Comment: String b [] = testField3.getText();  -- ??? это не будет работать.. вероятно вы опечатались.  Кроме того, Arrays.toString для массива чаров не сделает исходный текст, а напишет символы через запятую, что вряд ли то, что хотел автор вопроса.

Comment: согласен, поспешил. хотя это всего лишь примеры, как вариант - сойдет

Comment: Если testField3.getText() возвращает String (а судя по всем примерам это так), то вариант с String b [] = ... компилиться не будет.

Первый и третий примеры поместят **разные строки** в textField1.setText().

Однозначно понять, что хотел автор вопроса трудно, но скорее всего как в Вашем первом варианте т.е. получить строку вида: "a []=[q, w, e ...]"

Comment: окей согласен с вами. то потрясите бубном, узнайте что хотел автор, я лично удалю лишние варианты